# what is the mistake between passing argument and using it?

Tags: python

#a simple calculation

```
def choose_a_operator(operator):
    if operator==1:
         total=value1+value2
         return total
    elif operator==2:
        total=value1-value2
        return total
    elif operator==3:
        total=value1*value2
        return total
    elif operator==4:
        total=value1/value2
        return total

value1=int(input('Enter value'))
value2=int(input('Enter value'))

dict={1:'+',2:'-',3:'*',4:'/'}
print(dict)

operator=input("Enter operator shown above ")
#just to check value carried by this variable
print(operator)

print(choose_a_operator(operator))
```

I am trying to pass operator value to a function,choose_a_operator but the code inside the function is unresponsive.
However when i pass values like 1,2,3,4; The function tends to works correctly.
what am I missing here?

Comment: what you input for variable `operator` is in `str` but in the function you compare it as an `int`

Comment: With `value1` and `value2` you've proven that you do already know how to do it correctly...

Comment: You can [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `operator` object against integers (`1`, `2`, etc.) but `operator` is of `str` type.

I think you missed the type conversion to `int`:

```
operator = int(input("Enter operator shown above "))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
operator=int(input("Enter operator shown above "))
```

instead:

```
operator=input("Enter operator shown above ")
```

Answer (score 1):

operator should be integer, but input function returns string.
When specify operator as argument, you should write code like this.

```
print(choose_a_operator(int(oprator))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` always returns a string in Python 3, so you're getting the value `"1"`, which is not equal to the number `1`. Consider

```
operator = int(input("..."))
```